# How to access a TagField from a Django model as a column in postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I don't know how to select a column (skills) from a table in postgres for a Django tagfield (list of tags).

My model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    position = models.CharField(max_length =10000, null=True, default='', 
    blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length =10000, null=True, default='', 
    blank=True)
    skills = TaggableManager(help_text="A comma-separated list of tags.")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_image", blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, default='', 
    blank=True)
```

I've tried SELECT skills FROM users_customuser; and I get the error 'Skills column doesn't exist'

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using SQL?

Comment: Is there another database I should use? I'm trying to obtain a list of all the skills recorded in my website.

Comment: you should use `user.skills`

Comment: Flush your database, delete migrations folders, and try with this command: `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Comment: @shourav this doesn't work in postgres